# Allow user to select time zone

Tags: java, date, time, timezone

I'm writing a Java application where the user should be able to choose their time zone. I've listed all available with TimeZone.getAvailableIDs(), which gave back 627 lines. Obviously I won't ask the user to choose from that. How should I cover all time zones + use the correct daylight saving when applicable, with the minimum amount of choices?

Comment: Use an autocomplete input.

Comment: The `TimeZone` class is old and has some design problems, along with its friends like `Calendar` and `SimpleDateFormat`. I recommend that you switch to [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). Its corresponding class is `ZoneId` (with 627 available IDs too, though).

Comment: It’s correct, we are missing a time zone picker GUI component. Would be nice is we could use a world map and let the user point to a time zone. Failing that, one idea would be to let the user pick the continent first and then the city. It doesn’t solve the entire problem; there are far more than 100 zones for the America continent alone.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to provide an elegant time zone picker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26402074/how-to-provide-an-elegant-time-zone-picker) That one doesn’t have an upvoted or accepted answer, though.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZoneOffset;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class MainClass {

    public static void main(String[] argv) {

        Map<String, String> sortedMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();

        List<String> zoneList = new ArrayList<>(ZoneId.getAvailableZoneIds());

        // Get all ZoneIds
        Map<String, String> allZoneIds = getAllZoneIds(zoneList);

        // sort by value, descending order, use values as keys and vice versa
        allZoneIds.entrySet().stream().sorted(Map.Entry.<String, String>comparingByValue().reversed())
                .forEachOrdered(e -> sortedMap.put(e.getValue(), e.getKey()));

        // print map
        sortedMap.forEach((k, v) -> {
            String out = String.format("%5s (UTC%s) %n", k, v);
            System.out.printf(out);
        });
    }

    private static Map<String, String> getAllZoneIds(List<String> zoneList) {

        Map<String, String> result = new HashMap<>();

        LocalDateTime dt = LocalDateTime.now();

        for (String zoneId : zoneList) {

            ZoneId zone = ZoneId.of(zoneId);
            ZonedDateTime zdt = dt.atZone(zone);
            ZoneOffset zos = zdt.getOffset();

            // replace Z to +00:00
            String offset = zos.getId().replaceAll("Z", "+00:00");
            result.put(zone.toString(), offset);

        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Based on: https://www.mkyong.com/java8/java-display-all-zoneid-and-its-utc-offset/

When creating a timezone map I'm replacing keys with values so we are getting UTC differences as keys.

This outputs:

```
-12:00 (UTCEtc/GMT+12) 
-11:00 (UTCPacific/Midway) 
-10:00 (UTCEtc/GMT+10) 
-09:30 (UTCPacific/Marquesas) 
-09:00 (UTCSystemV/YST9YDT) 
-08:00 (UTCUS/Pacific) 
-07:00 (UTCAmerica/Shiprock) 
-06:00 (UTCAmerica/Winnipeg) 
-05:00 (UTCSystemV/EST5EDT) 
-04:00 (UTCSystemV/AST4ADT) 
-03:30 (UTCCanada/Newfoundland) 
-03:00 (UTCAmerica/Argentina/Buenos_Aires) 
-02:00 (UTCAtlantic/South_Georgia) 
-01:00 (UTCAmerica/Scoresbysund) 
+14:00 (UTCEtc/GMT-14) 
+13:45 (UTCPacific/Chatham) 
+13:00 (UTCEtc/GMT-13) 
+12:00 (UTCPacific/Majuro) 
+11:00 (UTCPacific/Guadalcanal) 
+10:30 (UTCAustralia/South) 
+10:00 (UTCAustralia/Lindeman) 
+09:30 (UTCAustralia/Darwin) 
+09:00 (UTCAsia/Tokyo) 
+08:45 (UTCAustralia/Eucla) 
+08:30 (UTCAsia/Pyongyang) 
+08:00 (UTCAsia/Singapore) 
+07:00 (UTCAsia/Saigon) 
+06:30 (UTCIndian/Cocos) 
+06:00 (UTCAsia/Thimphu) 
+05:45 (UTCAsia/Katmandu) 
+05:30 (UTCAsia/Calcutta) 
+05:00 (UTCIndian/Kerguelen) 
+04:30 (UTCAsia/Kabul) 
+04:00 (UTCEurope/Ulyanovsk) 
+03:30 (UTCAsia/Tehran) 
+03:00 (UTCW-SU) 
+02:00 (UTCEurope/Athens) 
+01:00 (UTCEurope/Monaco) 
+00:00 (UTCEtc/UTC)
```

Comment: My problem is that this doesn't consider daylight saving time, otherwise I'd just use offsets. (And it's quite confusing to choose Tokyo just because my offset is +9)

Comment: Then use all the time zones + autosuggestion. Because its obviously more than one city in each zone and even if you merge all of them you'll get something like `Pacific/Palau, Asia/Chita,Dili,Jayapura,Yakutsk,Seoul,Khandyga,Tokyo` which is also not very usable. And regarding saving time I remember there were a couple of countries which canceled (and then probbaly renewed) that so not sure if it can be tracked by API, maybe just add checkbox for DST

Comment: **ERROR** Use `Instant` instead of `LocalDateTime`. The `LocalDateTime` class has no concept of time zone or offset-from-UTC. So it cannot represent a moment, is *not* a point in the timeline. Your code could produce unexpected results if executing around the moment of an anomaly in some zone such as Daylight Saving Time (DST).

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about simplifying things and using [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time)? I've seen many websites that are interested in time zone of user use this. This should reduce it to around 24 options (there are some special cases that may increase it to ~40 if you're concerned about servicing *every* country and being 30 minutes for a couple is not an option). Then the only consideration is to ask them if they observe daylight savings. Implementing that would involve taking into account hemispheres.

Comment: As far as I know even the start and end date of daylight saving differs by country so UTC offset + a boolean won't solve the issue. :(

Comment: There’s a reason why there are 627 zone IDs. There are duplicates (alias IDs), admitted, but they can’t be reduced to 3 * 40 = 120. In particular, historic offsets differ and sometimes don’t divide by 30 or 15 minutes either, summer time (DST) is introduced or cancelled from year to year, so the same rules don’t apply this year as last year or next year. And so forth.